# What does "Strongly Typed" Actually Mean in Actionscript 3 for Both Flash and Flex?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flash-builder, flash-cs5

So strongly typed is referring to how you instantiate variables.

1. Clearly, this is not strongly typed:

   ```
   var _somevar = new VarClass();
   ```
2. But in flash you could do something like this:

   ```
   private var _guy:Sprite;
   ...
   var _varClass:Class = getDefinitionByName("VarSymbol") as Class;    
   _guy = new _varClass();
   ```

#### Is this second method strongly typed? Which is better for performance?

Or is it only considered strongly typed if you say:

```
private var _guy:VarClass;
```

Also I know in Flex you pretty much always declare the type as the name of the class. Is it true then that Flex uses strongly typed variables and Flash does not?

Answer (score 3):

> Also I know in Flex you pretty much always declare the type as the
>   name of the class. It it true then that Flex uses strongly typed
>   variables and Flash does not?

This was getting too big for a comment.

You seem to be confused as to what Flash and Flex are.  Flash primarily refers to either a browser based runtime named The Flash Player or a graphical IDE named Flash Professional.

Flex is formally a software development kit (SDK).  However, the term Flex can be used to refer to The Flex Framework, which is an ActionScript 3 UI framework.  It can also be used to refer to the Flex Compiler which is used to turn MXML and ActionScript into SWFs.

The current language of the Flash player is ActionScript 3.

If I'm understanding your question, then I would expect both Flash Professional and Flash Builder should apply the same constraints on ActionScript 3 code.

I would not consider ActionScript 3 to be a strongly typed language.  At best it is loosely typed.  The original code you shared:

```
var _somevar = new VarClass();
```

Will throw a warning from the Flex Compiler.  You could write the same line like this:

```
var _somevar : * = new VarClass();
```

It means that the type of the `_somevar` variable can be anything.

Another aspect I would expect in strongly typed languages is that you can specify the type of data objects in an Array.  ActionScript does not enforce all elements of an array to be of the same data type.  So, I could make an array that includes different types of objects, numbers, boolean values, and Strings.

Vectors, recently introduced in ActionScript are exactly like a typed Array.

All that said; most people approach ActionScript 3 development as if it were a strongly typed language.  They declare types on all their variables and Arrays don't mix values of different types.

Does this help?

Comment: I like the fact that you consider a 2008 evolution as recent. Most would consider something 5 years old as ancient nowadays. +1 for the explanation.

Comment: @Aralicia I guess the time got away from me. :-) Seems like Vectors were a much more recent addition...